# Designating a range as a string in data validation code

Tags: excel, vba, string, validation, range

I have a problem with a bit of code I am working on to designate a data validation set from a selection within another cell. For example, they choose Thomas, and every cell on a table that corresponds with "Thomas" is selected as the range from which to choose for another drop-down list.

The code mostly works, but doesn't quite come together. The last portion, the With .Validation portion, brings up a application defined error. I suspected it has to do with the rng being a range being treated as a string, so I've tried creating a separate string variable set as the address of rng, but that brought up an error too. I also tried (as seen below), just designating the address of rng as the data validation formula itself, which also results in an error.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub ProcessSelector()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Select
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In .Range("E1:E" & lastrow)
       If c.Text = "Thomas" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Range("C" & c.Row)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Range("C" & c.Row))
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select



With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D5")
  With .Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rng.Address
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

It would work the first time, and give me an error every time after that. The cause was that I needed to add

".Delete" after the with .Validation portion, to clear out the pre-existing data validation settings on that cell.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=listProcesses"
End With
```